# Is there anyway to get the removable drive name not the letter using batch script

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I have a requirement like where I have a tool called WINSCP.exe which can show me the folder structure of the device which I'm using. On that device I have a pendrive connected. In that tool inside media my pendrive is mounted and the name of the pendrive is shown.

Now I want that pendrive name to be get retrieved using a batch file.
It doesn't show to drive letter it just shows the name of the pendrive with which I can access the further tree inside it.

The device is linux based and I've tried some commands to open the tool of WINSCP but no luck with drive name.

```
open sftp://<usrnme>:<pwd>@172.16.21.145/
get "/usr/media/<pdname>" "D:\WinSCPDestination\"
```

---

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
         )
      )
   )
)
```

The for loop code I have got in stackoverflow but it is for windows. How can I check the name?

Comment: So you basically want to translate the Windows batch-file to some Unix script, right? If so, you are wrong here, unless you share what you have tried on your own so far, providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts, by [edit]ing the question...

Comment: Use `ls /usr/media` in your WinSCP script?